# How to redirect an entire site to a 404 page in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-code-404, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am looking for the correct way to redirect an entire site to a 404 page in the `routes.rb` file in a rails 3 application.

I can do a page using: `match 'url' => redirect("/404")`

But I want to know how to 404 all the pages without using adding a redirect to every route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails you can create a method to render 404's in the Application Controller, ActiveRecord and Abstract Controller:

```
def make_404
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('404')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in your ApplicationController like below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ... other code

  def redirect_to_404
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```

Then call that function within the controllers which handle the views you want to redirect.